# Python - Returning Multiple Lines of Code without Tuple

Tags: python, printing, return

I'm writing a python function and I want it to print out a shapes. I am limited to using print five times. The shapes prints out if I use:

```
def shape():
     print line1
     print line2
     print line3
     print line4
     print line5
```

And then print the shapes out multiple times by multiplying the function. However, this uses up all my allotted print statement and I need to also create another function that prints the same shapes, but indented to the right evert other line.

So I would like this function to return the whole shapes, so that I can use print statement later on. However, of course, if I use return instead of print, I only have line 1 returned and then the function stops. Is there any way to get around this? Using a tuple doesn't help me since I want the shape intact.

EDIT: I am not allowed to use "/n" or any extra quotations marks when writing my answer. I am given pre set strings that I can use.

Comment: Why are you limited to using print five times?

Comment: I don't know... arbitrary assignments in intro CS... right now I'm really regretting taking the intro class when I have experience--I thought it would be an easy A :-p

Answer (score 0):

presuming lines are in a list or tuple etc.. use join on wherever the container the lines are coming from.

```
def shape():
     return "\n".join(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5)
```

Or just return all lines and use join on the function:

```
def shape():
     return lines

print("\n".join(shape()))
```

For five lines `return lines[:5]`.

You can use join on any iterable:

```
def shape():
      return "\n".join(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5)
```

without using `\n` just iterate over the function using a single print:

```
def shape():
     return lines

for line in shape():
  print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple variables from a function:

```
def shape():
     return line1, line2, line3, line4, line5
```

and read them in the same way:

```
line1, line2, line3, line4, line5 = shape()
```

which means that if you want, you can create a "pretty print" function that reads the variables returned from `shape()` and adds tabs/newlines/whatever-you-want to each line - without messing your data:

```
def pretty_print_lines():
    for line in shape():
        print line
```

Comment: if I print shape() after writing that second line, I still print a tuple though?

Comment: @numbersloth I'm not sure I understood your comment: when you return multiple variables it's being auto-packed into a tuple and if you'll read it into multiple variables (the last line in the answer) python will unpack the tuple, which means that if you want, you can create a "pretty print" function that reads the variables returned from `shape()` and adds tabs/newlines/whatever-you-want to each line - without messing your data. I'll update the answer to show an example.

Comment: but if I enter those lines into my code, and write print shape(), python still prints a tuple...

Comment: ugh this is so upsetting--we aren't supposed to use "for" loops since we "haven't learned them yet" (I'm really regretting taking the intro class when I have experience--I thought it would be an easy A :-p )

Comment: @numbersloth if it's supposed to be *very* basic use of python, then I guess you're expected to do exactly what you did in your question (print line by line).

Answer (score 0):

Restricting this answer to the specs in the question:  You can use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) in the function and add an `indent` argument.

```
def shape(indent = 0):
    indent = ' ' * indent
    print '{}'.format('ab')
    print '{}{}'.format(indent, 'cd')
    print '{}'.format('ef')
    print '{}{}'.format(indent, 'gh')
    print '{}'.format('jk')

def indent5():
    shape(5)
```

Usage:

```
>>> shape()
ab
cd
ef
gh
jk
>>> indent5()
ab
     cd
ef
     gh
jk
>>>
```

There are a lot of variations you can add to that like a second argument to specify indenting the even or odd lines- which would require a bit more code in the function.